# Is there a tool to convert Java, JavaScript or Python to PHP?

Tags: php

I am interested in usging the library [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) with PHP. Unfortunately it is not available in this language. It is available "only" in Java, JavaScript, Dart, C++, C#, Objective C, Lua and Python.

So is there a tool to automatically convert one of those language into PHP ? Do you have other suggestions how I could use this library with PHP. I would like to avoid calling it via `exec()` to make the installation of my program simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automatic conversion? Will that ever work? Here is a PHP port: [diff_match_patch-php](https://github.com/mikkorantalainen/diff_match_patch-php).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to convert Java to PHP, but it does still require some manual intervention. See here: http://javatophp.com