# Save Javascript to File from PHP Variable

Tags: javascript, php

In Javascript, I have a function that creates a hash from a PHP GET variable. For example,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getHash{
    ...
}
var answer = "<?php echo $_GET["answer"];?>";
document.write(getHash(answer));
</script>
```

Right now this is outputs the hash to the page. Is there a way to save this hash to a file on the server?

Comment: Either send the hash using Ajax, or do `window.location.href = 'saveHash.php?hash=XXX';` and save it in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so with an ajax request. If you are not using JQuery, my code for sending an ajax request is attached bellow:

```
function getRequestObject(){
    var o = null;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        o = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else if(window.ActiveXObject){
        try{
            o = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        }catch(e1){
            try{
                o = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }catch(e2){

            }
        }
    }
    return o;
}
function request(method, adress,sendData,callback){
    var o = getRequestObject();
    var async = (callback!==null);
    if(method === 'GET'){
        if(sendData!=null){adress+="?"+sendData;}
        o.open(method, adress, async);
        o.send(null);
    }else if(method === 'POST'){
        o.open(method, adress, async);
        o.setRequestHeader('Content-Type' , 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        o.send(sendData);
    }
    if(async){
        o.onreadystatechange = function (){
            if(o.readyState==4&&o.status==200){
                callback(o.responseText);
            }else if(o.readyState==4&&o.status!=200){
                //Error
            }
        };
    }
    if(async){return ;}
    else{return o.responseText;}
}
```

What you try to do only makes sense if the function getHash uses variable user input. If that is not the case, and all the information to compute the hash is avialable at the server, you shoudl compute the hash directly at the server. Also be aware that a user can manipulate the hash value (if it is sent by javascript and not computed at the server).

Also you can save the hash in the session-variables on the server.

Comment: The hashing function is done in javascript and seems to be fairly complicated. I do not know how to port it to PHP otherwise that would solve all my issues :)

Comment: I do not see how to execute javascript on the PHP-Server yet but this questions is asking for something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454503/execute-javascript-server-side

Comment: @Bijan Could you post the function in a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? That might be fun to translate to PHP :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152804/is-there-a-tool-to-convert-java-javascript-or-python-to-php

Comment: Can you use this php function? http://php.net/manual/de/function.md5.php

Looks like we got the getHash function call here: console.log(ks_md5(answer));

Comment: @Bijan WOW! I'll give it a try, I'm bored. But I can't promess i'll succeed.

Comment: @tokam: Unfortunately I cannot use the PHP MD5 function, I have to use the posted function(s)

Comment: @Bijan I spent an hour trying to translate it, only to come back and see this. PHP's native `md5('abc')` returns the same value as your code. Why can't you use it? Sorry but I quit, I'm not familiar enough with bitwise operators ^^

Comment: I am an idiot. I didn't realize that long code was the equivalent of `md5_hex()`